# Custom role not listed

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, permalinks

I have a custom role called ***my_vendor*** which submits custom post called ***tour*** from the front-end. The issue is that the function ***wp_list_authors()*** is not listing the users having *my_vendor* role. However, if I create a default post from that user then the function lists that user. But if only custom post is created from that user, it is not being listed.

These are the capabilities for that custom role:

```
$admins->add_cap( 'level_1' );
$admins->add_cap( 'edit_post' );                                                   
$admins->add_cap( 'edit_posts' ); 
$admins->add_cap( 'edit_other_posts' ); 
$admins->add_cap( 'publish_posts' ); 
$admins->add_cap( 'read_post' ); 
$admins->add_cap( 'read_private_posts' ); 
$admins->add_cap( 'delete_post' );
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign a Custom Role to a Custom Post?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25383/assign-a-custom-role-to-a-custom-post)

Comment: Thanks for replying. However, I used the code from the link and modified it accordingly. The function `wp_list_authors` still shows only the admin role and not my custom role - https://prnt.sc/m7engb